# Certificate getting installed as trustedCertEntry instead of PrivateKeyEntry

Tags: ssl, keystore, keytool

We are trying to import the SSL certificate on Tomcat keystore by using the below command

```
keytool -import  -alias $HOSTNAME -file $HOSTNAME.cer -keystore keystore
```

The certificate is getting installed but is installed at `trustedCertEntry`, with this the https connection is not working. Whereas we've seen on other working servers the certificate was installed as `PrivateKeyEntry`.

How can we install the `cer` file as `PrivateKeyEntry`?

Any help or pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the same keystore and the same alias you used when creating the private key and the CSR.

Comment: that is what the problem was.